# Need a good reference on Levy-Ito decomposition and martingale spaces

Tags: probability, analysis, reference-request

I am currently using Appelbaum but it does not go into too much detail how we deal with the part with small jumps.

Can someone please recommend a good text book? I have Bertoin at my disposal, but I do not see to find anything in the index.

Also an intro of martingale spaces is appreciated. Appelbaum mentioned Rudin.(which rudin's book is it?) Is there any other?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

*Lévy Processes and Infinitely Divisible Distributions* by Ken-Iti Sato is a great source to Lévy processes and characterizations of such. It describes both the Lévy-Khintchine formula and the Lévy-Itô decomposition.